# Boot from CRAMFS partition on an emmc

Tags: filesystems, kernel, boot, u-boot

Have someone worked extensively with cramfs rootfs?

I created an emmc.img file in buildroot 2020.11.1.

(several partitions with two same rootfs.cramfs partitions, but loading from one of them at a time)

I have created two rootfs partitions in that image file , which are both defined as

a CRAM Filesystem. (have zImage and device tree inside a rootfs.cramfs in the folder /boot)

My **first problem** is that i have no clue how to handle these two partition from U-boot (2016)

I have following commands:

- cramfsls (should show directory from an image??) and
- cramfsload   (have to set environment variable cramfsaddr, from where the cramfs is loaded plus offset )

**Second problem** is that with mmc part  the rootfs.cramfs partitions are not visible, but both defined as bootable.

But i know startadress and number of sectors from every partition

(got from fdisk -l on my host pc inspecting the emmc.img)

Maybe i have some missunderstanding how to handle that, but have someone an idea here?

Thanks for every help i get!!

PS: I dont want ramdisks as these are regularly used with cramfs

Answer (score 0):

In U-Boot is v2021.4 **cramfsls** and **cramfsload** expect that environment variable **cramfsaddr** indicates the address to which you have loaded the cram file system.

You cannot use these commands before reading the file system into memory.

You can use command **mmc read** for this purpose

Comment: So if i have a cramfs partition on an emmc, its only possible to work with it inside memory? i thought that linux kernel could handle an cramfs only from an emmc. Is there an info link to that fact?  Thank you very much for that info!

Comment: Yes you have to first copy from eMMC to memory using mmc read. I am not aware of any documentation. I took my knowledge from reading the source: https://source.denx.de/u-boot/custodians/u-boot-arc/-/blob/master/cmd/cramfs.c . We have started building documentation in https://u-boot.readthedocs.io but that is still rather incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Xypron, Thank you very much for your input, it helped me a lot. I already tried to read the cramfs partition into the ram, but I had no success to read the directory structure with the uboot command **cramfsls** (cramfsaddr as environment variable points to the ram Adress where I loaded the cramfs Partition)
I edited the  genimage.cfg.template in a way to have two cramfs partitions (both bootable because zImage and devicetree are inside the boot directory of the rootfs) , but only one cramfs partition is made visible by buildroot. ( after loading emmc.img , the **mmc part** command was not able to make both cramfs partition visible). But that’s another problem with cramfs I have. It’s very weird that there is no solid documentation about it.(I will look forward reading the documentation you proposed) I hope I will find a workable solution.